# The results of `aws eks list-nodegroups` and `eksctl get nodegroups` are inconsistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

```
eksctl  get nodegroups --cluster=cluster-name --profile=dev
aws eks list-nodegroups --cluster=cluster-name --profile=dev
```

First result is correct 
Second result is air as follows:

```
{ 
    "nodegroups": [] 
}
```

I used these two commands to get the nodegroup of the cluster, but found that the results were not consistent.  
The configuration file I used was the same ~/.aws/config.  
The cluster_name was checked by the command. Come out, these two commands can correctly detect cluster  but cannot detect nodegroup 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What versions of `aws` and `eksctl` are you using?

Comment: I installed it according to the aws document, it should be the latest version, aws-cli/2.0.38 eksctl/0.25.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to eksctl [documentation](https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/#listing-nodegroups):

> #### Listing nodegroups
>
> To list the details about a nodegroup or all of the nodegroups, use:
>
> `eksctl get nodegroup --cluster=<clusterName> [--name=<nodegroupName>]`
>
> #### Nodegroup immutability
>
> By design, nodegroups are immutable. This means that if you need to
> change something (other than scaling) like the AMI or the instance
> type of a nodegroup, you would need to create a new nodegroup with the
> desired changes, move the load and delete the old one. Check
> [Deleting and
> draining](https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/#deleting-and-draining).

And for `list-nodegroup` from AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/list-nodegroups.html#list-nodegroups)

> Lists the Amazon EKS managed node groups associated with the specified cluster in your AWS account in the specified Region. Self-managed node groups are not listed.

As you can see there are differences in these commands such as Self-managed node groups are not listed in the second command.